# Tcl How to modify csv and it can control another file's data without using tcllib

Tags: csv, tcl

I have many files of process and it contain  versions, I have regexp certain line of them and import them into a txt file , the txt format is like

```
   #process #AA_version       #BB_version
   a11      Aa/10.10-d87_1    Bb/10.57-d21_1
   a15      Aa/10.15-d37_1    Bb/10.57-d28_1
   a23      Aa/10.20-d51_1    Bb/10.57-d29_3
```

and then I change the txt to csv format like

```
,#process,#AA_version,#BB_version
,a11,Aa/10.10-d87_1,Bb/10.57-d21_1
,a15,Aa/10.15-d37_1,Bb/10.57-d28_1
,a23,Aa/10.20-d51_1,Bb/10.57-d29_3
```

And now I want to write a tcl(get_version.tcl) it can generate the corresponding version (in the file where I regexp the version) after parsing the csv file

ex. If I tclsh get_version.tcl to parse csv file, input the process I want to modify(a11) and it will `puts` the current version AA_version: `Aa/10.10-d87_1` BB_version: `Bb/10.57-d21_1` and I can modify the version
and the get_version.tcl can update the csv file and the file (where I regexp) at the same time.

Is that available? and I cannot install tcllib , can I do these thing without tcllib?
It contains too much commands, I don't know how to start, Thanks for help~

If I want to change the AA_version of process a11, and use

```
get_version.tcl a11 
AA_version = **Aa/10.10-d87_1** 
BB_version = **Bb/10.57-d21_1**
```

It will read the csv file and add the new version(ex.Aa/10.13-d97_1 ), and this action will change the file  (1.add a new line AA_version =Aa/10.13-d97_1  2. modify AA_version = Aa/10.10-d87_1 ->#AA_version = Aa/10.10-d87_1) in original file

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want. Can you edit your question to include the output that you want to see.

Comment: You really want a blank column at the start of each csv record? That's… unusual.

Comment: Why can't you install tcllib?

Comment: Hi @glennjackman,  my final purpose is to modify csv file to change the content of the original file

Comment: I want to read/modify csv file and replace the new version in the original file

Answer (score 1):

I'd process each line something like this:

```
split [regsub -all {\s+} $line "\u0000"] "\u0000"
```

(The tcllib `textutil::splitx` command does something similar.)

If you don't have commas or quotes in your input data — and it looks like you might be able to guarantee that easily — then you can just `join $record ","` to get a line you can write out with `puts`. If you *do* have commas or quotes or stuff like that, use the Tcllib csv package because that handles the tricky edge cases correctly.

---

As a simple stdin→stdout filter, the script would be:

```
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    set data [split [regsub -all {\s+} $line "\u0000"] "\u0000"]
    # Any additional column mangling here
    puts [join $data ","]
}
```